# Select All Field Contents using InputMask jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using the inputMask jQuery plugin, and I'm wanting to select the entire contents of a field when the field comes into focus.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$('.numbers-only').inputmask("numeric", {
  radixPoint: ".",
  groupSeparator: ",",
  digits: 2,
  autoGroup: true,
  prefix: '',
  rightAlign: false,
  positionCaretOnClick: "select",
  oncleared: function () { self.Value(''); }
});
```

Someone suggested adding:

```
positionCaretOnClick: "select",
```

Which did not work. The field contents do not get selected.

I've also tried this:

```
$(document).on('click, focus', '.highlight-on-focus', function() {
    $(this).select();   
});
```

Which also did not work as intended.

Instead, the caret position is simply going to the end of the string.

How can I solve this problem?

TIA,

Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an instance of [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) is running on an input, it seems like the plugin handles *things* on focus... Don't ask me what!

But it seems that if you have a `setTimeout()` as short as 1ms, the `select()` works.

Have a look the chained `.on()` method below. ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.numbers-only').inputmask("numeric", {
    radixPoint: ".",
    groupSeparator: ",",
    digits: 2,
    autoGroup: true,
    prefix: '',
    rightAlign: false,
    //positionCaretOnClick: "select",
    oncleared: function () { self.Value(''); }
  }).on("focus",function(){
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.select();
    },1)
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/css/inputmask.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>

<input class="numbers-only" value="2200.23">
```

Comment: You're welcome... Next time, please care to indicate exactly which plugin you use... You will have faster answers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change for the code that you wrote and it should be like this:

```
$(".numbers-only").focus(function(){
       $(this).select();
});
```